# Reading multiple separated parts of data in .csv format, divided by empty rows and tagged with numbers indicating each datasets

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file of time series datasets, but these datasets are given in "discontinuous" form, separated by empty rows and tagged with its sequence numbers. Its form looks like the attached photo below:

The starting point of the datasets which should be exploited for the desired calculation.

[image: The starting point of the datasets which should be exploited for the desired calculation]

The ending point of the datasets:

[image: The ending point of the datasets]

Since I would like to calculate the time integral for each "Samples" of the data sets, it is necessary to read "separated parts" of the given .csv files.

However, due to my insufficient skills for constructing python code (literally I just started writing python codes and have to handle such kind of data), I am only aware of methods reading desired parts of continuous data manually (by using loc of pandas), which its row is not divided. I would appreciate if I can get some advise for this matter.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current code, some sample input of your data as text (not as an image) and also the desired end result. That way we can better help you.

Comment: In my personal opinion, I think it is difficult for beginners to handle such unprocessed data. In addition, it is difficult for others to solve this kind of problem because it is difficult for the questioner to provide [mre]. However, if you provide minimal and reproducible as a text type, we will be happy to solve it for you!

Comment: These pictures do not seem to show how fragments of data are separated. So where are you at, exactly? Do you get an error while reading the csv into a pandas dataframe, or do you have a pandas dataframe from which you would like to remove empty rows? if case 1: please post code and error / if case 2: please post a portion of the dataframe. In any case, replace the images and post [text instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). For dataframe: the output of `print(df)` is a good start.

Comment: In my opinion, Pandas won't be able to do the initial separation. You will need to read it into Python as a text file, and separate it into separate well-formed CSVs. (Or do this in any text editor, if easier.)